# Using a second z-buffer as a stencil buffer (depth-stencil test)

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, stencil-buffer, zbuffer

Here's my situation:

I'm using OpenGLES 3.0.

I'm doing z-buffer shadow casting.  HOWEVER, I also have some cuts in the scene that are done with a stencil buffer, i.e. to dig "holes" in the ground that are not geometry.

I am using a stencil buffer to not allow shadowing in the holes.  BUT, the problem with this is, the stencil buffer prevents shadowing all the way forward in the scene, so if something occludes the hole but is also in shadow, I will see a nonshadowed "hole" where there should be shadow.

So, my plan was to have a second z-buffer, and simply write the stencil masks into that zbuffer.  When trying to draw my shadow pass, I would simply check my z-value against the other zbuffer and skip drawing if greater than or equal, but allow drawing if less than.

However, I don't seem to be able to read the value of the other z-buffer and get it to compare correctly to gl_FragCoord.z.

I want to do:

```
vec2 otherZ=texture(otherZ,uv).r;
if (otherZ>=gl_FragCoord.z) discard;
```

But, I am not getting consistent results.  Do I have to run some kind of conversion on the value in the other z-buffer?  Is gl_FragCoord.z different from the value that ends up in the z-buffer?

Edited to add: This is the format of my stand-alone depth buffer:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8,mWidth,mHeight,0,GL_DEPTH_STENCIL,GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8, NULL);
```

Comment: Clear the stencil buffer when you draw your non-hole opaques?

Comment: Not really an option because the holes can be "moved" and there's no good way to say "the hole is in this geometry, but not in this other geometry."  I really just need some way to tie the stencil to a Z... I don't mind making another z buffer, I just need to know how to get an EXACT match to what the card plans to write into Z normally.

Comment: What does "not consistent" mean? You'll get all the usual depth precision issues that normal shadow mapping has, so need to account for that.